# Document.SaveAs2 without saving macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to run a macro in a `*.docm` file but, once the routine it's over, the document has to be saved as a `.docx` file. After, this new file has to be opened to avoid making the final user open the file generated by himself and so, make the file's usage comfortably. 
 
I need the macro to do this because of a trusting issues. 
 
I use the code below:

```
Dim source As Document, copy As Document

Set source = Documents(1)

Dim l1 As InlineShape, l3 As InlineShape

With source
    .Bookmarks("Logo1").Select

'Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=UserForm1.Label2 & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & UserForm1.Label3.caption & "/logo1.jpg", _
                        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True



    l1.LockAspectRatio = True
    l1.Height = CentimetersToPoints(2)

    .Bookmarks("Logo3").Select

Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=UserForm1.Label2 & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & UserForm1.Label3.Caption & "/logo3.jpg", _
                        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True


    l3.LockAspectRatio = True
    l3.Height = CentimetersToPoints(2)

    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView

    GetFileName 'This is used to type the name of the file to be saved as docx

    Dim fName As String

    fName = UserForm2.TextBox1.Text & UserForm2.Label2.Caption

    .SaveAs2 fileName:=fName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, SaveFormsData:=False
    Set copy = Documents.Open fName

End With
```

If I run this macro with the code pasted above, creates a `.docx` file with the same code that the `.docm`has and runs the macro again. 
I have tried to remove the code using this function that I found in a website:

```
Sub DeleteAllVBACode()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set VBProj = ActiveDocument.VBProject

    For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
            Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            End With
        Else
            VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        End If
    Next VBComp
End Sub
```

But I get an error, so I have tried to remove it using this:

`copy.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove copy.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")`
`copy.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove copy.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")`

After running the code with these two lines, the `.docx` has code still.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Using this sub, works perfectly:

```
Sub RemoveAllMacros(objDocument As Object)
' deletes all VBProject components from objDocument
' removes the code from built-in components that can't be deleted
' use like this: RemoveAllMacros ActiveWorkbook ' in Excel
' or like this: RemoveAllMacros ActiveWorkbookDocument ' in Word
' requires a reference to the
' Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library
Dim i As Long, l As Long
    If objDocument Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    i = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    i = objDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i < 1 Then ' no VBComponents or protected VBProject
        MsgBox "The VBProject in " & objDocument.Name & _
            " is protected or has no components!", _
            vbInformation, "Remove All Macros"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With objDocument.VBProject
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            On Error Resume Next
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(i)
            ' delete the component
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With
    With objDocument.VBProject
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            l = 1
            On Error Resume Next
            l = .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
            .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, l
            ' clear lines
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Provided by **Exceltip** in http://www.exceltip.com/modules-class-modules-in-vba/delete-all-macros-in-a-workbookdocument-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html